# PHP: Group array by index (every 1,2,3,nth...)

Tags: php

I can't figure it out how to convert array to different group, like every 1 , 2 , 3,...nth.

Something like this.

```
$number_of_group=3;
$data = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

Output

```
$data = [ 
           '0':('a','d','g'),
           '1':('b','e','h'),
           '2':('c','f','i')
        ]
```

Comment: please add your code and where it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the array and add every third item in each array.
I use a counter `$i` that counts and I use the modulo of 3 (number of groups) to know what array to store it in.

```
$number_of_group=3;
$data = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];

$i = 0;
foreach($data as $item){
    $new[$i][] = $item;
    $i = ++$i % $number_of_group;
}

var_dump($new);
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "g"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "e"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "h"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "i"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/8K31T